# Buying NFT from opensea

Tags: ethereum, nft, opensea

Is it possible to buy NFT from OpenSea marketplace without using the SDK?

I tried to get the TX data from the OpenSea browser, but I think it's not possible because of the SDK.

I was checking requests and responses when pressing on buying button, but no request is related to the buying, and no response includes TX Data.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pull the order structure and signature from the Opensea API, and then just send that order with the buyer's signature (that you have to prompt) in order to fulfill an order.
The process:

1. get order from Opensea API
2. get buyer's signature
3. submit order to Seaport SDK to fulfill order

Here's the code for 1)

```
 var contract = req.query.contract;
        var token_id = req.query.tokenID;
        const options = {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: { Accept: 'application/json', 'X-API-KEY': API-KEY }
        };

        fetch('https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/assets?token_ids=' + token_id + '&order_direction=desc&asset_contract_address=' + contract + '&limit=20&include_orders=true', options)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response)
                res.send(
                    {
                        wyvern_orders: response.assets[0].sell_orders,
                        seaport_sell_orders: response.assets[0].seaport_sell_orders
                    }
                )
            })
            .catch(err => {
                res.send({ msg: "error", err: err })
            });
```

I had this above integrated into a different api to call separately, so below you will see it as a fetch to that url to fetch that data. Also, you will see me prompt the user for their signature and then, I will send the order to Seaport's fulfill order.

```
export async function buyNFT(contract_address, token_id) {

        const buy = async() => {
            try {
                // create the seaport instance with the provider
                const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
                const seaport = new Seaport(provider);
                const url = "www.personalApiURl.com/..."
                const options = {
                    method: "GET",
                }
                // get the buyer and order
                let buyer = await getBuyer()
                let data = await fetch(url, options)
                let res = await data.json()
                if (res["seaport_sell_orders"] === null) {
                    console.log("Error getting orders, may not exist for NFT")
                    return
                }
                // get the order for that listing
                let full_order = res["seaport_sell_orders"][0]["protocol_data"]
                // calculate the tip
                let new_tip = await getTip(full_order["parameters"])
                if (new_tip === "E") { 
                    console.log("error getting tip")
                    return 
                } // return if can't get price
                // now execute buy order
                if (typeof seaport !== "undefined" && full_order) {
                    const { executeAllActions: executeAllFullfillActions} = await seaport.fulfillOrder({
                        order: full_order,
                        tips: new_tip,
                        accountAddress: buyer
                    })
                    const transaction = await executeAllFullfillActions()
                    if (transaction[code] === 4001) {
                        console.log("They denied transaction")
                        return
                    }
                }
            } catch(error) {
                console.log("Error in purchasing NFT")
                console.log(error)
            }
        }

        async function doAll() {
            // await sell()
            await buy()
        }
        doAll()
    }
```

Here's the calculateTip function as well. This is needed if you wanted to add an extra tip or fee to another address. This is enabled through the Seaport SDK.

```
async function getTip(full_order) {
        // calculate the tip pricing 
        const receiver_address = "0x0"
        //get the full real price without fees
        let real_price = getRealPrice(full_order["consideration"])
        if (real_price === "E") {return "E"}
        // if you have a price, calculate tip
        let tip_percent = ethers.BigNumber.from("100")
        let price = ethers.BigNumber.from(real_price)
        let tipping_price = price.div(tip_percent)
        // create the tip
        let new_tip = [{
            itemType: 0, //ETH
            token: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000", 
            identifier: "0",
            amount: tipping_price,
            recipient: receiver_address
        }]
        return new_tip
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Askar, according to your solution, who is gonna sign that transaction? I read on this (https://github.com/ProjectOpenSea/opensea-js) and it can not sign the transaction? I don't know how to create a provider with private key. Can you help me?